# Yii2 dynamic form wbraganca onchange not wowrking

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic, yii2, onchange

Im using yii2 dynamic form wbraganca for creating dynamic rows.This is working fine for me.
I have a category dropdown in the form where onchange im loading a  based on the value in the dropdown. If the value in the dropdown is others? then im loading this div which has a textbox where user can enter his other category.

This onchange is working fine for the first Row when i click on new row, a new row will be generated but in that the other option is not loading the textbox.

Below is my form code and java script code.

```
     <?=   $form->field($bill, "[{$index}]category")->dropDownList(['Grocery' =>'Grocery', 'Power' => 'Power', 'Electricity' => 'Electricity', 'Water' => 'Water','others'=>'others'],['prompt'=>'Select...','onchange' => 'return showout(this.value)'])->label(false); ?>
```

Div which is loaded on change

```
  <div   id="mydiv" style="display: none;width: 88px;">
  <?= $form->field($bill, "[{$index}]other_category")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>  
  </div>
```

Java script code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function showout(a)
{
    if (a == 'others') {
        $('#mydiv').show();
    } else {
        $('#mydiv').hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `class` instead of `id` :

```
<?= $form->field($bill, "[{$index}]category")->dropDownList(['Grocery' =>'Grocery', 'Power' => 'Power', 'Electricity' => 'Electricity', 'Water' => 'Water','others'=>'others'],['prompt'=>'Select...', 'onchange' => 'showout($(this))'])->label(false); ?>
<div class="mydiv" style="display: none;width: 88px;">
    <?= $form->field($bill, "[{$index}]other_category")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>  
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function showout(category)
{   
    var index  = category.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    if (category.val() == 'others') {
        $("#bill-"+index.concat("-other_category")+"").closest('.mydiv').show();
    } else {
        $("#bill-"+index.concat("-other_category")+"").closest('.mydiv').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I tried this before.. It doesn't work. when i have 2 rows if i select 'others' in second row it is taking same for 1st row also. For both other textbox will be displayed or else no.

Comment: @SalmanRiyaz. Tested and working, check console for any errors. What is your modal name? Bill or anything else.

Comment: I added js code like this `<?php  
 $script = <<< JS
function showout(category)
{   
    var index  = category.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    if (category.val() == 'others') {
        $("#bill-"+index.concat("-other_category")+"").closest('.mydiv').show();
    } else {
        $("#bill-"+index.concat("-other_category")+"").closest('.mydiv').hide();
    }
}
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>`                                    Im getting this error in CONSOLE.... Uncaught ReferenceError: showout is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Comment: @SalmanRiyaz. Your function not defined. Try wrapping inside `document.ready`

Comment: Even after giving `document.ready`. its giving same error. `<?php
$script = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function(){
     function showout(category)
    {   
        var index  = category.attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
        if (category.val() == 'others') {
            $("#bill-"+index.concat("-other_category")+"").closest('.mydiv').show();
        } else {
            $("#bill-"+index.concat("-other_category")+"").closest('.mydiv').hide();
        }
    }
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>`